# Taylor expansion for Gâteaux derivative

Tags: functional-analysis, taylor-expansion, gateaux-derivative

Let $\mathbb{X}$ be a normed Space and 
$
f: \mathbb{X}\mapsto\mathbb{R}
$ 
is twice **Gâteaux** **differentiable** (not necessary Fréchet differentiable). Is it possible to build a Taylorexpansion for $f$ in the following sense

$
f(u)= f(\bar{u}) + f'(\bar{u})(u-\bar{u})+\frac{1}{2}f
''(\bar{u}+\theta(u-\bar{u}))(u-\bar{u})^2,
$

with $\theta\in(0,1)$?

Comment: Yes. Just Taylor expand the function of one real variable $g(r)=f(\overline{u}+r u), $ where $r\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: I am not really sure why this should be the same, since the second Gâteaux dirivative f'' could be discontinuosly.

Comment: That could be a problem even if X is $\mathbb R$. My point is that this general case is actually exactly the same as the one-variable case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this holds. It is basically a consequence of Darboux's theorem and the mean value theorem.

As indicated by Giuseppe Negro, it is sufficient to discuss the case of real arguments. Further, by simple transformation, it is sufficient to consider the situation
$$f(0) = f'(0) = 0, \quad f(1) = 1$$
and we will show the existence of $t \in (0,1)$ with $f''(t) = 2$.

First, we claim that there exists $t_1 \in (0,1)$ with $f''(t_1) \ge 2$.
We argue by contradiction and assume $f''(t) < 2$ for all $t \in (0,1)$.
The function $f'$ is differentiable, hence it has the mean value property. For every $t \in (0,1)$ we have $\hat t \in (0,t)$ with
$$ \frac{f'(t)-f'(0)}{t} = f''(\hat t) < 2,$$
i.e., $f'(t) < 2 \, t$. Now, the fundamental theorem of calculus yields
$$f(1) - f(0) = \int_0^1 f'(t) \, \mathrm{d}t < \int_0^1 2 \, t \,\mathrm{d}t < 1$$
which is a contradiction. This shows the existence of $t_1$.

Similarly, we can show the existence of $t_2 \in (0,1)$ with $f''(t_2) \le 2$.

If $f''(t_1) = 2$ or $f''(t_2) = 2$, we are finished. Otherwise,
$f''(t_1) > 2$ and $f''(t_2) < 2$. Hence, Darboux's theorem implies the existence of $t$ between $t_1$ and $t_2$ such that $f''(t) = 2$.